# SQLAlchemy: filter on operator in a many-to-many relationship

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I have two classes with a many-to-many relationship, `Items` and `Categories`.

Categories have an associated value.

I would like to query for all `Items` for which the highest `Categorie.value` (if there is any) is less than a given value.

So far I have tried queries like this:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import functions 
Session.query(Items).join(Categories,Items.categories).filter(functions.max(Categories.value)<3.14).all()
```

But in this case I get a `(OperationalError) misuse of aggregate function max()` error.

Is there a way to make this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` instead of just `WHERE` for filtering on an aggregate.

```
Session.query(Items).join(Items.categories).group_by(Items.id).having(functions.max(Categories.value)<3.14).all()
```

Edit: To also include Items without any category, I believe you can do an outer join and put an `OR` in the `HAVING` clause:

```
Session.query(Items).outerjoin(Items.categories).group_by(Items.id)\
.having( (functions.max(Categories.value)<3.14) | (functions.count(Categories.id)==0) )\
.all()
```

Comment: thank you. I reallize that my initial question was not precise enough. Some items do not have any category and I would like to retrive them as well. So maybe my intent was to find all items which dont have any category with an associated value of more than X.

Comment: Thank you a lot. Your answer was very helpful in my understanding of both sqlalchemy and sql.